# How to make LEFT JOIN in criteria api jpa without related entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, criteria-api

I am trying to make a `LEFT JOIN` in criteria api jpa without related entities (They are bound by foreign keys.). For this, I found only this option:

`cb.equal(userRoot.get("userId"), productRoot.get("productId"))`

But this option does `INNER JOIN`, which is not suitable for me.
I would be grateful for the instruction!

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with a difficult solution, if the cross is by ID, if there is not a very high data volume, you could make two queries, one on each table, and treat the data later with lambdas and java 8 stream, obtaining a performance Similary.